# do table associations in rails create columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm learning rails and am doing associations - has_many, belongs_to, etc. Do declaring relationships like this generate columns in the tables? I am using a MySQL database and was expecting to see a *thing*_id column, but there wasn't one.

Comment: `Associations` won't create `columns`.They just implement the `relation` between the models.You need to `manually` create the columns by generating the `migrations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the migration that create the columns. Here are 3 examples:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

      # This creates a field address_id
      t.references :address

      # This is equivalent as above
      t.integer :address_id

      # This special case for polymorphic association creates 2 fields
      # address_id and address_type
      t.references :address, polymorphic: true
    end
  end
end
```

In your model, the association only tell rails how to link the records but do not modify the database

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Tells rails that users.address_id is linked to addresses.id
  belongs_to: address
end
```

Comment: how does rails implement this association?

Comment: The whole thing is explained here in details http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html